# How to write this JPA select statment in CriteriaBuilder

Tags: jpa, jboss, jpa-2.0

For example, this is to retrieve a member from the database based on email:

```
    CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Member> criteria = cb.createQuery(Member.class);
    Root<Member> member = criteria.from(Member.class);        

    criteria.select(member).where(cb.equal(member.get("email"), email));

    return em.createQuery(criteria).getSingleResult();
```

Now if I want to add one condition, retrieve the member where email and password are both used. How should I write the 'select' statement?

```
criteria.select(member).where(cb.equal(member.get("email"), email));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you plan to support multiple criteria with optional values, collect them in a collection of **predicates** and use the `CriteriaQuery<T> where(Predicate... restrictions);` method. 
This allows you to not only include multiple required criteria filters in where clause, but also ignore criteria that have no value(e.g.because the user did not fill them in).
Example

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Member> criteria = cb.createQuery(Member.class);
Root<Member> member = criteria.from(Member.class);        

//create a holder for all conditions in `where` clause
List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
criteria.select(member).where(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates.length()]));

//email is required
predicates.add(cb.equal(member.get("email"), email));
//password is required
predicates.add(cb.equal(member.get("password"), password));

//'status' is optional, only add it if it was not empty
if (status != null) {
  predicates.add(cb.equal(member.get("status"), status));
}

return em.createQuery(criteria).getSingleResult();
```

If the `status` attribute is supplied and is not null, the where clause will contain 3 conditions, if it is null, there will be only 2.

This is much easier to maintain especially for queries with more filters.

One additional suggestion: use [JPA Metamodel](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjiup.html) to avoid type errors and ensure type safety checks at compilation time. Depending on the JPA implementation you use, you may need to add some additional libraries to your project, e.g.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

Change the **where** clause to be like this

```
where(cb.equal(member.get("email"), email), cb.equal(member.get("password", password));
```